Use synthetic bean from a quarkus extension in a company extension
For our company, we are trying to create an extension that wraps some bussiness logic that is shared across applications.
For this extension, we have a class that uses a connection factory. This connectionFactory is produced ty quarkus-artemis-jms as a synthetic bean.
Example
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Record(ExecutionTime.RUNTIME_INIT)
@BuildStep
EventProducerBuildItem loadEventProducer(
       // EventProducerRecorder recorder,
                                         BeanContainerBuildItem beanContainerBuildItem,
                                         ArtemisJmsConfiguredBuildItem artemisJmsConfiguredBuildItem,
                                         CrvJmsRunTimeConfigs crvJmsRunTimeConfigs,
                                         EventProducerRecorder eventProducerRecorder,
                                         BuildProducer<SyntheticBeanBuildItem> syntheticBeanProducer

) {


    ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = beanContainerBuildItem.getValue().beanInstance(ConnectionFactory.class);
    LOG.info("JMSConnectionFactory: " + jmsConnectionFactory);
    LOG.info("Loading EventProducer");
    syntheticBeanProducer.produce(SyntheticBeanBuildItem.configure(EventProducer.class).scope(Singleton.class).runtimeValue(eventProducerRecorder.eventProducerSupplier("how_to_use_the_jms_connection_factory"));

    return new EventProducerBuildItem();

}

I' ve been trying for a few days to find a way to generate and register our class EventProducer, that has ConnectionFactory as a field, in a buildstep and also as a synthetic bean . How do I get a handle on this connection factory produced by another extension?
Does anyone have good examples?

You can consume a synthetic bean just like any other bean. Can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

I've added an example. I'm struggling on how to tellt he recorder that is needs a connectionFactory and where it need to pick it up.

The mising link in my knowledge was the existence of
.addInjectionPoint(ClassType.create(DotName.createSimple(XAConnectionFactory.class)))
